# Reindexing DataFrame and merge two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a CSV file of a stock price that looks like this:

```
Index Date       Time Open High Low Close
0     01/01/2000 900  10   12   9   11
1     01/01/2000 901
```

What I want to do is drop the actual index, merge the Date-Time columns as one, and use it as an index formatted as a Panda TimeSeries.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is Time? Time in seconds, days or what?

Comment: I'm guessing it's 9:00 am

Answer (score 1):

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['01/01/2000'], 'Time':['900']})
    # Make it 24 hour time by adding leading zero
    df['DateTime'] = df['Date'] + ' 0' + df['Time']  
    # Let pandas figure out the datetime structure
    df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])
    df.set_index('DateTime', inplace=True)

>>> df
                           Date Time
DateTime
2000-01-01 09:00:00  01/01/2000  900
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['01/01/2000', '01/01/2000'], 'Time': [900, 901], 'Open': [10, None],
                     'High': [12, None], 'Low': [9, None], 'Close': [11, None]})
```

It can be not better solution, but it works.

```
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
data['Minutes'] = data['Time'].astype(str).str[-2:] #get minutes from Time
data['Hours'] = data['Time'].astype(str).str[:-2] #get hours from Time
#set to index Date and Time
data.index = data['Date'] + pd.to_timedelta(data['Hours'].astype(int), unit='h') + \
    pd.to_timedelta(data['Minutes'].astype(int), unit='m')
```

**Output:**

```
                          Date  Time  Open  High  Low  Close Minutes Hours
2000-01-01 09:00:00 2000-01-01   900  10.0  12.0  9.0   11.0      00     9
2000-01-01 09:01:00 2000-01-01   901   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN      01     9
```

And then just drop columns:

```
data.drop(['Date', 'Time', 'Minutes', 'Hours'], 1)
```

**Final output:**

```
                     Open  High  Low  Close
2000-01-01 09:00:00  10.0  12.0  9.0   11.0
2000-01-01 09:01:00   NaN   NaN  NaN    NaN
```

Comment: Probably easier to add the date and time columns together and let pandas to_datetime method do the rest.

Comment: @Chris yeah, you are right, your solution is better = ) But let my answer be here, it may be helpful.

Comment: Anna thanks a lot, in this specific case your code worked fine!